# Node-style callbacks: done(exception) or throw exception?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

As I can see, it is common to see this line:

```
if (err) return done(err);
```

But as I understand it right, I can do this:

```
if (err) throw err;
```

Which looks pretty and works good. So what's a difference?

And yea, I know about promises and I like 'em, but still, I want to know answer for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
if (err) throw err;
```

if the error is fatal and you want your program to crash, because there is no way to catch such an error. If you write a library or a server application you should pass error to callback.

Comment: Really? I thought promises catch these exceptions and wrap it with catch callback. It is true?

Comment: The question wasn't about promises, was it? Inside promise you can throw exceptions safely, it's true, but you don't need to rethrow errors because they propagate automatically.

Comment: Yea, is was a bit of off-topic ) So, w/o promises, I should always @done(err)@ if I want to catch it in upper logic and deal with it, but it error is fatal, I should throw it to notify myself with email or so?

Comment: it's always better to use `return callback(err);` (don't forget `return`), so you can always handle the error upstream. I use `throw err;` if I'm writing some automation script and it is ok that it crashes and prints stacktrace.

Comment: @vkurchatkin What does return do? The callback IS the upstream. Return does nothing in asynchronous code and misleads future maintainers into thinking the code is synchronous.

Comment: @slebetman `return` stops the execution of the function. It's just nice style to have `if (err) return done(err);` at the top of the function rather than `if (err) { done(err); } else { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Since most errors are asynchronous, you probably want to use a callback to propagate the error back to the error handler.

Try/catch blocks are seldomly used, and only for the few synchronous functions which might fail, like `JSON.parse()`.